# ajax login form, reloading onto the form rather than page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

so I have a login form where I used ajax to catch the login errors i.e. "incorrect password" from my login.php, and to display them onto the same login form rather than reloading a new page with the error message. That now works fine, but when the login IS successful it now loads the entire logged in page onto the login form rather than loading it to the entire page! You can see in the picture below.
[login ajax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU1GI.jpg)
Here is my code for the ajax:

```
 $("#login_button").click(function(){

    $.post($("#login_form").attr("action"), $("#login_form :input").serializeArray(), function(info){$("#login_errors").html(info);});
    // Prevent the default action from occurring.
    return false;
});

$("login_form").submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

and here is my code for my login form:

```
<form id= "login_form" action="login.php" method="post">
    <span id="login_errors" style="color:#F00;"></span>
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required"/>
    <br />

    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required"/>
    <br />

    <div class="checkbox">
    <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="keep" />
    <label for="remember">Keep me signed in</label>
    </div>

    <div class="action_btns">
    <div class="one_half last"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-blue" id="login_button" value="Login"></div>
    <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_form" class="btn">Sign up</a></div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Can anyone see what the issue is here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because your ajax callback does the same thing every time. No matter what is returned, it goes into `$("#login_errors").html()`.

What you might want to do is send back a json with a page url if you succeed. Then you could do something like this:

```
$.post( $("#login_form").attr("action"), 
  $("#login_form :input").serializeArray(), 
  function(info){
    if(info.urlRedirect!=null) 
       window.location.href = info.urlRedirect;
    else $("#login_errors").html(info);
  });
```

To do this, you would need to modify your `php` server side component to do something like this:

```
<?php
$success = $_REQUEST['s'];
if($success) {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('urlRedirect'=> '/home.php'));
} else {
    echo "<div>wrong username or password - please try again</div>";
}
?>
```

This is just a sample to show how you return a JSON with a URL if your login succeeds, and to return an html string (which would be your login form) if login fails.

If you do this, and you set a breakpoint inside of your `function(info){}` in your javascript, you will find that on success, `info` has a `urlRedirect` property. And on failure, you will find that `info` is just a regular string with html data.

Comment: I tried your code, but now it loads the login.php again :/

Comment: why is that happening?

Comment: Can't tell without more information. What is your php page passing back on successful login? Is it a JSON, and what is the value of urlRedirect?

Comment: well on successful login it would go to my home.php, which is the home page after a user has logged in.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by urlRedirect?

Comment: I added a brief sample of the server side component in my answer. Hopefully this will clarify things.